# VMware blocked usb access from Physical Machine

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, vmware, removable

The problem is I cannot access my usb stick from the real machine.

If I insert the usb and i have "Removable Devices" turned ON on my virtual machine I have full access and functionality on it. When I turn it OFF, even though you'd expect to have access from your host machine, the device fails to appear on my physical machine.

Even when I close the VMware player, I still don't get access. I've tried killing some vmware procs but got no result.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the faulty USB port in Device Manager seemed to work.